# Beginner - Stack class returns the reference of the object, not the name

Tags: java, object, stack

Here is my code for a project I am writing. The idea is to travel to different planets and have these "Planets" be pushed onto the custom stack class I have made. I am currently trying to make a method that pops off these object based planets as you type them in. However, I am having trouble writing it.

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StackX theStack = new StackX(99);

    String current = "Enterprise";
    int logOut = 1;
    String planetName;
    int secretCode;
    //This is the start out, do not loop this
    System.out.println("You are on the enterprise, where would you like to teleport?");

    //while loop will be done after reaching Io
    do {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Grab input from user
        System.out.println("Enter a planet name: ");
        planetName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a the four digit code for " + planetName + ": ");
        secretCode = input.nextInt();

        if (current.equals("Enterprise")){

            if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Europa") && secretCode == 9007){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Europa = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Europa);
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Titan") && secretCode == 1232){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Titan = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Titan);
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Rhea") && secretCode == 5623){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Rhea = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Rhea);
            } else {
                logOut = 0;
                System.out.println("You are dead.");
            }

        } else if (current.equals("Titan")){

            if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Enterprise") && secretCode == 1212){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Enterprise = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Enterprise);
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Rhea") && secretCode == 5623){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Rhea = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Rhea);
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Elara") && secretCode == 1264){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Elara = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Elara);
            } else {
                logOut = 0;
                System.out.println("You are dead.");
            }

        } else if (current.equals("Rhea")){

            if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Enterprise") && secretCode == 1212){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Enterprise = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Enterprise);
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Titan") && secretCode == 1232){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Titan = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Titan);
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Europa") && secretCode == 9007){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Europa = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Europa);
            } else {
                logOut = 0;
                System.out.println("You are dead.");
            }

        } else if (current.equals("Europa")){

            if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Enterprise") && secretCode == 1212){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Enterprise = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Enterprise);
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Rhea") && secretCode == 5623){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Rhea = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Rhea);
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Metis") && secretCode == 2535){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Metis = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Metis);
            } else {
                logOut = 0;
                System.out.println("You are dead.");
            }

        } else if (current.equals("Elara")){

            if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Titan") && secretCode == 1232){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Titan = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Titan);
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Metis") && secretCode == 2535){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Metis = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Metis);
            } else {
                logOut = 0;
                System.out.println("You are dead.");
            }

        } else if (current.equals("Metis")){

            if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Europa") && secretCode == 9007){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Europa = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Europa);
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Elara") && secretCode == 1264){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Elara = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Elara);
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Io") && secretCode == 4792){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Io = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Io);
                System.out.println("You have acquired the Macho Orb!");
            } else {
                logOut = 0;
                System.out.println("You are dead.");
            }

        } else if (current.equals("Io")){

            if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Metis") && secretCode == 2535){
                current = planetName;
                Moon Metis = new Moon(planetName, secretCode);
                theStack.push(Metis);
            } else {
                logOut = 0;
                System.out.println("You are dead.");
            }

        } else {
            logOut = 0;
            System.out.println("You are dead.");

        }

    } while((!current.equals("Io")) && (logOut != 0));

    //Pop method

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Return to the Enterprise using the same path.");


    System.out.println("Enter a planet name: ");
    planetName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a the four digit code for " + planetName + ": ");
    secretCode = input.nextInt();
    while(!theStack.isEmpty() ){
        if(planetName.equals(current)){
            theStack.pop();
        }
    }

}
```

Stack class:

```
class StackX { 
private int maxSize;        // size of stack array 
private Object[] stackArray; 
private int top;            // top of stack 

public StackX(int s)         // constructor 
  { 
  maxSize = s;             // set array size 
  stackArray = new Object[maxSize];  // create array 
  top = -1;                // no items yet 
  } 

public void push(Object j)  // put item on top of stack 
  { 
  stackArray[++top] = j;     // increment top, insert item 
  } 

public void pop()         // take item from top of stack 
  { 
  if(stackArray[top]!=null){
   stackArray[top]=null;
   top--;
  }
  } 

public Object peek()        // peek at top of stack 
  { 
  return stackArray[top]; 
  } 

public boolean isEmpty()    // true if stack is empty 
  { 
  return (top == -1);  // = =  returns true or false 
  } 

public boolean isFull()     // true if stack is full 
  { 
  return (top == maxSize-1);  // =  =   returns true or false 
  } 

}  // end class StackX
```

Moon class (Creates moon objects):

```
class Moon {
private int code;
private String name;

public Moon(String name, int code){
    setName(name);
    setCode(code);
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public int getCode(){
    return code;
}

public void setName(String newName){
    name = newName;
}

public void setCode(int newCode){
    code = newCode;
}
```

The pop method I am trying to write is here. I thought about using the peek() method from the stack class to compare the input going in to the top of the stack, but the peek() method only returns a reference to the peek object. Is there a better way to do this? I would like to compare the name and the code (int value) of the object to the input given if possible. I know the code is very messy with no methods, but please help a noobie.

```
//Pop method

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Return to the Enterprise using the same path.");


    System.out.println("Enter a planet name: ");
    planetName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a the four digit code for " + planetName + ": ");
    secretCode = input.nextInt();
    while(!theStack.isEmpty() ){
        if(planetName.equals(current)){
            theStack.pop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Of course it returns an object reference. That's what you're putting in your stack. Your `while` loop logic is also wrong. It will go to an infinite loop.

Comment: @Kayaman I know the while loop will be infinite, the last part is just a rough outline of how it needs to be. I just need to know how to compare the object name and code instead of the reference if possible

Comment: That's why you have the `getName()` method in your Planet class. Is this code all yours? Because it seems odd that you would write so much code and then have problems with calling a method on your own class...

Comment: I have written all this code, my object based programming knowledge is a bit rusty that's why. I know the getName() and getCode() method can return the name and code for the object, but I am having trouble implementing it.

Comment: But you've done the comparison that you need, for planets.  Doing it for moons won't really be any different.

Comment: @DavidWallace the comparison for planets was easier considering that is a String, but I honestly have no idea how to compare a string to the object. Even with the get methods

Comment: @Outright Your get methods return a String. Get the planet's name from the Moon object, and compare that. You know, like `planetName.equals(planet.getName());`. Then go read a basic tutorial, because this is just ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you need a searchable collection here, rather than stack. You should use a `List` to hold your objects. Later, you can iterate over it and check for the required object.

See

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.htm

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm

Comment: They're obviously meant to write their own Stack class.